# Data model and queries for rentals and customers using SQL / PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I got similar data model as on picture below, and wanted to know following things (I am trying to learn PostgreSQL so I would appreciate statements in it):

1. customers who have a Rent starting in the last XY days
2. customers who have more than XY rent in the category ‘category’ starting in the last XY months
3. For each day of June 2019, how many Rs are active on a given day ?(R is active between its start/return date). *Date Series

I am not so experienced in SQL statements but wanted to get some inputs...

Maybe solution to the 3rd:

```
SELECT 
   date_trunc('day', rental_date) m,
   count (customer_id)
from rental
where rental_date >= '2021-11-01'
and   return_date < '2021-12-01'
group by 
m
order by
m;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these queries.

```
SELECT C.Name AS CusomterName,
       R.*
FROM Customers C
JOIN rentals R
  ON C.customer_id = R.customer_id 
WHERE start_date > current_timestamp - interval '30 day';


SELECT C.Name AS CusomterName,
       COUNT(*)
FROM Customers C
JOIN rentals R
  ON C.customer_id = R.customer_id 
JOIN line_items L
  ON R.id = L.rental_id
WHERE L.category = 'Production'
      AND start_date > current_timestamp - interval '6 months'
GROUP BY C.Name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5;    


SELECT t.dd,
       COUNT(*) filter(WHERE t.dd BETWEEN R.start_date AND R.return_date) AS ActiveRentals
FROM rentals R 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT generate_series(timestamp'2021-11-01', '2021-11-30', '1 day')::DATE AS dd) t
GROUP by t.dd;
```

Comment: Wow, thats it I assume! Those JOINS were hard for me to understand. Can you just check my solution for 3rd answer? Thanks a lot btw!

Comment: @Mirza - For #3, what do you want to show when there is no active rental on a specific day? The issue I see with your query is that you are not going to see dates for which there is no active rental. If you are okay with that, the solution will work.

Comment: Thanks! You have actually right, I need all dates.

Comment: Question about first query, why "R.*"? It gives me all columns actually, whereby I needed Customers only, right?